# sqoop: Error when tried to import table from database

Tags: hadoop

When used the below command to import the data from the database "MyData", error occured.

> sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/MyData --table My_Practice --username sa -P --target-dir /userPavan/table -m 1

But when the database name is not given as below, no error occurred.

```
>sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://localhost --table My_Practice --username sa -P --target-dir /userPavan/table -m 1
```

But i need to run the command with the database name..Can anyone suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:port/databaseName --table My_Practice --username sa -P --target-dir /userPavan/table -m 1`

Sqlserver default port is 1433.

Comment: Used the same as you suggested, but the error is getting repeated... Could you please help me ..

Comment: Error: ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost/hive, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection proprties,check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".ERROR manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list columns from query: SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=(SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()) AND TABLE_NAME='mytable' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION